# Python on list event

Tags: python, discord

I'm looking to make a program that has a list, and when it senses some change in that list it triggers an event. Sort of like:

```
list = ["1", "2", "3"]
check_list = ["1", "2", "3"]

while True:
    if list != check_list:
        print("List has changed.")
```

But i can't use any loops as this is just a small part of the code and that would stop the entire code.

so something like this would be good:

```
list = ["1", "2", "3"]
check_list = ["1", "2", "3"]

on list != check_list:
    print("List has changed.")
```

or

```
when list != check_list:
    print("List has changed.")
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can just write an if condition like `if list != check_list: print("List has changed.")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `function` here:

```
def is_changed(list,check_list):
    if list!=check_list:
        return True
    return False

list = ["1", "2", "3"]
check_list = ["1", "2", "3"]

print(is_changed(list,check_list))
if is_changed(list,check_list):
    trigger_your_event()
```

Comment: Will you please give some example? If functions are async mode it should work. Or you can call this function as callback.

Comment: Make a try to your code to check whether it works or not